# What does this MySQL function output when written like this?

Tags: php, mysql, function, date-format

I've ordered a project from a developer, and I'm trying to fix the errors I find along the way.

One is a MySQL query with the DATE_FORMAT() function, that makes the query not return anything.

```
SELECT * FROM food_cart 
WHERE cart_userId='3' 
AND cart_itemId='8' 
AND date_format(cart_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H')='".date("Y-m-d")."'
```

The code seems to be correctly formatted, as it does not return an error when executed in phpMyAdmin. It does however, not return anything.

The table looks like this:

[image]

I think it is supposed to try to look at just the date (i.e. 2011-10-07) and not the exact time, as it is not relevant for the query. I'm just a beginner at MySQL and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing here.

Any help appreciated!

Mike.

Comment: It looks like you are running blind with the date format(s) being returned. For experimental purposes, try a query whith the two items you wish to compare such as `select cart_date, curdate() as foo from food_cart limit 4` and then see what the fields look like and then decide if they are matchable. This way you know what the data you are comparing looks like to the engine and then you can figure out how to get a comparison which will evaluate to true. Once you have that, you can then create the comparison. I suspect date(cart_date) = date(curdate()) is what you want.

Comment: @horatio: initially I tried the same, but it returns an error using this: http://pastie.org/2659685. I'm not sure how to do the comparison you suggested, but I'll try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here's my version of [Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689141/what-does-this-mysql-function-output-when-written-like-this/7689188#7689188):

```
$date = date( "Y-m-d", $timestamp );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM food_cart
        WHERE cart_userId = '3' 
          AND cart_itemId = '8' 
          AND cart_date >= '$date'
          AND cart_date < '$date' + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
```

This query will

- make full use of an index on `cart_date`,
- make full use of the query cache, and
- return exactly those rows for which the date part of `cart_date` equals `$date`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not need date translation for its own fields.
Just make sure you input your parameter in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',$adate);

$query = "SELECT * FROM food_cart 
WHERE cart_userId = '3' 
  AND cart_itemId = '8' 
  AND cart_date BETWEEN '$date' AND DATE_ADD('$date', interval 1 day) 
  -- and car_date <> DATE_ADD('$date', interval 1 day)
```

If you are walking this query day by day uncomment the last part to eliminate the 1 second overlap that is in the all-inclusive BETWEEN. This will prevent spurcious duplicates.

Comment: It doesn't need date translation, but if cart_date = someday @ 1600 and the adate = someday @ 0000, the dates won't equate...

Comment: I think you have `date()` in the wrong place: you want `date(cart_date) = '$date'` instead.

Comment: Neither of the two returns anything :/

Comment: @ilmari, no that is exactly what you never want you never put fields in functions because then you cannot use an index!

Comment: @mike its a bad idea to use a datetime because its hard to match it against a single day often better to use date then you can just use '=' much easier and faster

Comment: Well, yes, but a slow solution that works is still better than a fast one that doesn't.  Anyway, I see you've changed your answer to use `BETWEEN`, which should also work (and be faster than my suggestion above).

Comment: @ilmari, Note that it does include 1 second on the wrong day because between is all inclusive this may not look like a big problem but if you are walking through it day by day ypu may get duplicates if you dont want that ypu should add 'and car_date <> DATE_ADD('$date', interval 1 day)' to avoid the overlap

Comment: True... you could just use `cart_date >= '$date' AND cart_date < '$date' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`.

Comment: I know but i just realized the between problem and wanted to highlight the problem with it. Using > < is much better and faster too.

Comment: @ilmarikaronen: Really appreciate all the help guys! Both solutions work, but I'm gonna go with ilmari's solution. Post it as an answer and I'll select it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use function date() instead. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: Something like this: http://pastie.org/2655891
???? It doesn't work.. again - not very familiar with MySQL. I'm trying to get the entries with the specified values and the current date, as there can be multiple dates

Answer (score 0):

When `date("Y-m-d")` is passed to the query, it assumes 00:00:00 for the hours, minutes, seconds. That's why it's not returning anything. you might need to do a range search to get from midnight to 11:59:59 of that same date.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
date_format(cart_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H')='".date("Y-m-d")."'
```

This will produce something like the following (that will never be correct):

> '2011-10-07 16' = '2011-10-07'

Instead do

```
 date( cart_date )='".date("Y-m-d")."'
```

If you're comparing dates, make sure that both sides of the equation have the same level of precision.

*Edit:* here's the full cleaned-up PHP code:

```
$date = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$sql = 'SELECT * '
     . 'FROM food_cart '
     . 'WHERE cart_userId = 3 '
     . '  AND cart_itemId = 8 ' 
     . "  AND date( cart_date ) = '$date'";
```

It should generate a statement like `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND date( cart_date ) = '2011-07-10'` which will handle the date-filtering properly.

Comment: This does not work :/. The statement looks like this:

AND 'date(cart_date)'='2011-10-07'

Comment: @Mike.  Don't put the single-quotes around 'date(cart_date)'.  I'll update with full SQL code.

Comment: @Mike One thing to note in the edit above.  The first line `$date=date()` is using *PHP's* `date` function to create a string 'YYYY-mm-dd'.  Then you insert that string into the SQL statement and use *MySql's* `date` function to extract date info from "cart_date" field and compare it to your `$date` PHP string.  This is the same as using `date_format( cart_date, '%Y-%m-%d' )` like you were originally using (but without the unecessary %H).